# Using Babel in Production - How to precompile scripts

Tags: oracle, reactjs, babeljs, oracle-apex

I'm building an application using Oracle Application Express (APEX) [so no existence of Node].

I have two issues which are somehow related concept-wise.

**Issue #1:**

I've included the React.js library in all of my pages to use some of its features.

I'm using babel to convert my JSX to simple JS. Everything's working fine.

But I keep on getting this warning in my console :

```
You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. 
Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
```

I know I must precompile my scripts but I have no idea how. I visited the link and it got me all the more confused.

**Issue #2:**

The other issue I have is that I've got all my react related code in a separate .js file and I have embedded it in my page using this :

```
<script src="someJSFile.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Setting the type to **"text/babel"** raises this warning :

```
Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated 
and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. 
See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details.
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1:** This is linked to what ever bunlder you choose (see issue 2 below). Which ever you do choose, will allow you to set the node env to production, which will put React in "production" mode - basically scraping out all the unneeded (but helpful) development messages and checks.

**Issue 2:** You will need some module bundler at the end of the day. Webpack is the goto at the moment. [Webpack Site](http://webpack.github.io)

Alternatives include:

- Gulp + Browserify
- Rollup

EDIT: I know you said "no node". You won't need node to run anything on the server, only on your local machine where you build the files. Node is easy to install on pretty much any local machine

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm still having issues on how to compile my JSX. And I can't find any proper tutorials on the net for it.

Comment: As a followup I found this part of the babel website which does the compiling for me :
https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Just a heads up - that link is great for testing out features, but as your site grows you will want to move into a module bundler of sorts (webpack, gulp, etc). If you really don't feel like getting that all set up and want something that just works, you can try codekit which now supports jsx, babel, etc. It's a paid solution, but you won't have to set anything up

Comment: The problem is I can't find a proper tutorial on how to set up webpack to compile JSX to JS. Otherwise I'd be more than willing to give it a go

Comment: Do you have an example config? If that is your only requirement, it should be straight forward enough

Comment: No, I'm completely empty-handed

Comment: Start with https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/#the-simplest-configuration then slowly build up until something doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure why you unaccepted the answer - it covers everything you actually asked?

Comment: Chris, I actually clicked on accept. Something must have gone wrong??!!