# What is meant by 'precompilation' of scripts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, babeljs

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
    const element = <div className="container">Hello World</div>
    ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement)
  </script>
</body>
```

Chrome is showing a warning: "babel.js:100428 You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - [https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/"](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/%22).

What does this mean? What is meant by 'precompilation' of scripts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Babel in Production - How to precompile scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852937/using-babel-in-production-how-to-precompile-scripts)

Comment: @AllanWind I want to know what is meant by 'precompile'?